# AWS EC2 java run error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I'm new to the AWS EC2, and I want to run a java class `MyServer` in an EC2 instance by executing a `run.sh` script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ec2-user/
java MyServer
```

MyServer.java

```
package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jokes[] = {"j1", "j2", "j3"};

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9000);
        while(true){
            Socket s = socket.accept();
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            String ip = (InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            print.println(ip+jokes[(int)(Math.random()*(jokes.length-1))]);
            s.close();
            print.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled the code by installing the compiler `yum install java-devel` and then `javac MyServer.java`

The instance's current work directory is `/home/ec2-user`, and I have `MyServer.class` and `run.sh` in this folder.

When I execute `sh run.sh` in the instance, I received `Error: Could not find or load main class MyServer Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: server/MyServer (wrong name: MyServer)`

I tried to solve it by using different class names in the .sh script, ie `server.MyServer`, `MyServer.class` but none of them works.

Comment: This is unrelated to EC2 or AWS and just a pure Java issue. What does your Java code look like? Do you have a main class / method? Do you have packages? How did you compile the code?

Comment: I would suggest that try to run on your system before running on ecs2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `package server;` from the code, it works. It seems that the package was added by java automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Change your shell script to something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh


(cd /home/ec2-user/ && java MyServer)
```

Otherwise, by the time the shell interpreter reaches `java MyServer` the current directory has changed back to the original current directory.

Comment: thank you but I still receive the same error `Error: Could not find or load main class MyServer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: server/MyServer (wrong name: MyServer)`

Comment: If you want to keep the package, which is encouraged in Java, change `java` to `java -cp .`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a package called **server** and you are ignoring it in your bash script. Check whether **/home/ec2-user/** have got the folder **server** or not. If compilation is successful then it will have it.
Next, modify your script with **java server.MyClass** without entering into server folder(package), and you shall be able to execute it successfully.

I have been able to execute this code on my local system:

```
package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jokes[] = {"j1", "j2", "j3"};

        System.out.println("Server Started!");

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9000);
        while(true){
            Socket s = socket.accept();
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            String ip = (InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            print.println(ip+jokes[(int)(Math.random()*(jokes.length-1))]);
            s.close();
            print.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the shell code for compiling and running:

```
saad@saadsap:~/java_barebone$ javac server/* -d out/
saad@saadsap:~/java_barebone$ cd out/
saad@saadsap:~/java_barebone/out$ java server.MyServer 
Server Started!
```

Note: Flag **-d** is for destination folder which can be omitted.

Comment: I don't have a server folder after compiling, but I got MyServer.class in `/home/ec2-user/` . It seems like it compiled but failed to generate a `server` folder ?

Comment: have you tested in your own system?

Comment: In your case, just simply try this:
javac server/* (Enter)
java server.MyServer  (Enter) 
(output->)Server Started!

Note:This is not a good idea to generate class files where source is.

Comment: when I run `javac MyServer/* -d out/` I got error `error: invalid flag: MyServer/*
Usage: javac <options> <source files>`

Comment: your package name is "server" not MyServer. MyServer is your class name

Comment: javac server/* NOT MyServer since your package is "server"